# Update DataTable with values from ListView

Tags: c#, listview, webforms, datatable

This is the scenario:
I have a web page with a ListView lv_create_claim which contains a nested ListView lv_fees which contain textboxes.
On update_button click I need to validate all values in textboxes on database. Procedure will return status and validation errors. If there are any errors I need to repopulate lv_fees textboxes with entered values. So I need to keep all entered data in session. To accomplish this I update session DataTable iterating through all textboxes in all nested lv_fees.
Here is the question. Is there any better and more efficient way to update session DataTable with values I get from ListView.

```
    DataTable dt = HttpContext.Current.Session[ "PopulationData" ] as DataTable;

    int i = 0;
    foreach( ListViewItem item in lv_create_claim.Items )
    {
      ListView fees = item.FindControl( "lv_fees" ) as ListView;

      DataRow row;

      foreach( ListViewDataItem x in fees.Items )
      {
        row = dt.Rows[ i ];
        row.BeginEdit();
        row[ "claim_amt" ] = PFFormat.GetCurrency(( x.FindControl( "txb_cliam" ) as TextBox ).Text);
        row[ "start_date" ] = ( x.FindControl( "txb_from_date" ) as TextBox ).Text;
        row[ "end_date" ] = ( x.FindControl( "txb_from_date" ) as TextBox ).Text;
        row.EndEdit();

        i++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: it will be much better if you use your custom class's object instead of DataTable

Comment: Couldn't you just store the listview itself in Session?

Comment: Thank you Waqas Raja for the suggestion. Lets say I change it to custom object. Do I still need to iterate trough all ListView items or there is a better way to update custom object values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question does not make much sense. Close it.

Comment: want to close my own question.